# NodeMCU Server side cannot send things to client side - multiple clients attached

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, communication, wireless

I technically need your help, when I am working on my project, I found out that my server-side cannot send data to the client-side, my server-side is made with `WiFiServer(80)` so it is when my client-side do `client.print`, it can send to the server-side, and the server-side just easily send to the Python side with Serial, and Python can still send it to the server-side, but the server-side cannot send it to the client-side.  The basic [code is from this page](https://www.instructables.com/id/WiFi-Communication-Between-Two-ESP8266-Based-MCU-T/)

1. Server Code

Here's the code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#define led LED_BUILTIN
char ssid[] = "AP";
char pass[] = "Science_Fair";
WiFiServer server(80);
WiFiClient client;
IPAddress ip(10, 241, 241, 27);
IPAddress gateway(10, 241, 241, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
int i;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(100);
  }
  // Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  server.begin();
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  client = server.available();
  client.setTimeout(3000);
  Serial.setTimeout(2000);
  if (client)
  {

    // Serial.println("Available");
    if (client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Connected");
    }

    while (client.connected())
    {
      // Serial.println(".");

      String request = client.readStringUntil('e');
      if (request == "LR")
      {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);
        Serial.println("LR");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
          String reply = Serial.readStringUntil('e');
          if (reply == "WARN_B")
          {
            Serial.println("Confirm");
            client.print("WARN_Be");
            break;
          }
          yield();
        }
      }
      else if (request == "RR")
      {
        Serial.println("RR");
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
          String reply = Serial.readStringUntil('e');
          yield();
          if (reply == "WARN_A")
          {
            Serial.println("Confirm");
            client.print("WARN_Ae");
            break;
          }
          yield();
        }
        yield();
      }
      yield();
    }
  }
  // Serial.println("");
  client.stop();
}
```

2. Client A Code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DFPlayer_Mini_Mp3.h>
#define PIR_A D3
#define PIR_B D8
#define led LED_BUILTIN
const char ssid[] = "AP";
const char pass[] = "Science_Fair";
SoftwareSerial DFPlayer_Mini(D1, D2);
WiFiClient client;
IPAddress server(10, 241, 241, 27);
IPAddress ip(10, 241, 241, 28);
IPAddress gateway(10, 241, 241, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(PIR_A, INPUT);
    pinMode(PIR_B, INPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    DFPlayer_Mini.begin(9600);
    mp3_set_serial(DFPlayer_Mini);
    mp3_set_volume(30);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int i;
    float time = 0;
    int PIR_A_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_A);
    int PIR_B_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_B);
    client.connect(server, 80);
    client.setTimeout(1500);
    if (PIR_A_VAL == HIGH)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            time += 1;
            delay(1);
            if (time >= 1000)
            {
                Serial.println("OFD");
                for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    delay(100);
                    yield();
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (PIR_B_VAL == HIGH)
            {
                if (time == 1)
                {
                    client.print("RRe");
                    client.flush();
                    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                    {
                        delay(100);
                        yield();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            PIR_B_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_B);
            yield();
        }
    }
    else if (PIR_B_VAL == HIGH)
    {
        String fromServer = client.readStringUntil('e');
        yield();
        if (fromServer == "WARN_A")
        {
            mp3_play();
        }
        Serial.println("B Triggered");
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            delay(1250);
            yield();
        }
    }
    Serial.println("OFL");
    client.stop();
}
```

3. Client B Code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DFPlayer_Mini_Mp3.h>
#define PIR_A D7
#define PIR_B D8
#define led LED_BUILTIN
const char ssid[] = "AP";
const char pass[] = "Science_Fair";
SoftwareSerial DFPlayer_Mini(D1, D2);
WiFiClient client;
IPAddress server(10, 241, 241, 27);
IPAddress ip(10, 241, 241, 29);
IPAddress gateway(10, 241, 241, 254);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(PIR_A, INPUT);
    pinMode(PIR_B, INPUT);
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    DFPlayer_Mini.begin(9600);
    mp3_set_serial(DFPlayer_Mini);
    mp3_set_volume(30);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(100);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int i;
    float time = 0;
    int PIR_A_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_A);
    int PIR_B_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_B);
    client.connect(server, 80);
    client.setTimeout(1500);
    if (PIR_A_VAL == HIGH)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            time += 1;
            delay(1);
            if (time >= 1000)
            {
                Serial.println("OFD");
                for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    delay(100);
                    yield();
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (PIR_B_VAL == HIGH)
            {
                if (time == 1)
                {
                    client.print("LRe");
                    client.flush();
                    for (i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                    {
                        delay(100);
                        yield();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            PIR_B_VAL = digitalRead(PIR_B);
            yield();
        }
    }
    else if (PIR_B_VAL == HIGH)
    {
        String warnStatus = client.readStringUntil('e');
        yield();
        if (warnStatus == "WARN_B")
        {
            mp3_play();
        }
        Serial.println("B Triggered");
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            delay(1250);
            yield();
        }
    }
    Serial.println("OFL");
    client.stop();
}
```

I've tried:
 - Using `client.print` instead of `client.printf`
 - Using data with underlines instead of spaces
 - Added `client.flush`
 - Added `client.stop`
 - Changed NodeMCU
 - Checked wires
 - Checked power supply
 - Checked the data to send
 - Made the timeout longer
 - Checked speaker
But none of them is working

Please help me guys I'm in a rush, thank you!

Comment: try to create a minimal reproducible example without workaround attempts

Comment: @Juraj I already did that tho, it is working, but I couldn't solve the problem with that way

Comment: And it is almost the same tbh ( I found one, not coded one )

Comment: The link is [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/WiFi-Communication-Between-Two-ESP8266-Based-MCU-T/), I used this guy's example

Comment: the code in the instructable is nice and clean. why is yours so cluttered?

Comment: @Juraj uh technically I need to add a lot of things some HC-SR501 and a lot of things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read through the instructable and found - hidden in the comments the following

> Author of the instructable: 
>  Would you like to send message to the
>   four clients in the same time?
>
> If it is right I can not support you. I am not a expert in this topic.
>   My server sends message to the current client only which is triggering
>   the server. Using my sketch you can send same message to the clients,
>   but in different time. (Remark codebreaker007: which would not work anyway!)

So this solution you have in your code is supposed to work with only one client. So you have to implement yourself a kind of com-sequence wether sever triggered or client side.
Here a short how to add this functionality:

```
#define MAX_SRV_CLIENTS 4 // max clients connecting

WiFiClient serverClients[MAX_SRV_CLIENTS];
```

in the loop do the following:

```
  uint8_t i;
 for (i = 0; i < MAX_SRV_CLIENTS; i++) {
  //check if there are any new clients
  if (server.hasClient()) {
 //find free/disconnected client spot
  if (!serverClients[i] || !serverClients[i].connected()) {
    if (serverClients[i]) serverClients[i].stop();
    serverClients[i] = server.available();
    Serial.print("New client: "); Serial.print(i);
    break;
  }
 }
```

So you can differentiate between the clients and send with for loop to all or

```
 serverClients[2].print("WARN Client 2");
```

Hope this resolves the issue (And read also comments of instructables about problems - the author is actually a newbie)

Comment: Uh sorry I couldn't understand you, do you mean by that I need to give it a few more code to it so it can work with more than one client?

Comment: YES your solution is only for one client!

Comment: Oh man tks, this freacking problem has taken me over a month, deeply thank you

Comment: But I am at home now, I can only test at my lab, so I'll test it tmr, tks

Comment: I've already given you best answer!

Comment: WAIT! No need for WiFiServer?

Comment: #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>  look into the library examples, this lib supports client and server code

Comment: Sorry my brain was dead haha tks bro

Comment: the code in the instructable takes the current client, handles it, closes the connection and forgets the client. then it can handle the next client.

Comment: This does not help the OP if he wants to do Server initiated communication with two or more clients attached at the same time